# react-native run-android fails with "Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED" After installing react-native-fbsdk

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

After following the installation instructions of [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#react-native-fbsdk), the command 
    react-native run-android 
fails with the following error:

```
info JS server already running.
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
C:\projects\veida\veida_v1\Erua3\android\app\src\main\java\com\erua3\MainActivity.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   class Intent
  location: class MainActivity
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
24 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 23 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I have tried reinstalling android studio and following the installation steps two times with two new projects.

My App.js is the default App.js. I have also tried using the example App.js with the facebook login.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by adding in your imports in MainActivity.java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
```

Also, This error mostly comes when your sdk version is different with `react-native-fbsdk` version. for example: let's say, SDK Version in your `build.gradle` is:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "27.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}
```

But it is different in your react-native-fbsdk

So you need to check whether you are using the same sdk version.

> Go to node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle and comare
>   the version with your project build.gradle.

Comment: my project does not have `react-native-fbsdk` in node_modules?

Comment: @RajnishCoder this solution is not specific about only fbsdk, it can happen with any module, sometimes you dont have the same target versions in your build.gradle and your module's build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Try this

How I solved this problem:

First, make sure that I have %java_home% variable set and also %path% has the java sdk included.
[How to setup Java environment variables](https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10)

Second, Go to your android folder and run this command:

```
C:\Projects\myproject\android>gradlew.bat app:installDebug.
```

> Unzipping
>   C:\Users\codeb.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv\gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
>   to
>   C:\Users\codeb.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv
>   Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in
>   opening zip file
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:225)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:155)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:169)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:215)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

As you can see that my gradle download is corrupt. All you have to do is delete this folder and rerun the command.

```
C:\Projects\myproject\android>gradlew.bat app:installDebug
```

> Downloading
>   https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
>   ...............................................................................................................
>   Unzipping
>   C:\Users\codeb.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv\gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
>   to
>   C:\Users\codeb.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv
>
> Welcome to Gradle 4.10.2!
>
> Here are the highlights of this release:
>    - Incremental Java compilation by default
>    - Periodic Gradle caches cleanup
>    - Gradle Kotlin DSL 1.0-RC6
>    - Nested included builds
>    - SNAPSHOT plugin versions in the `plugins {}` block
>
> For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/release-notes.html

Now, you can go back to your react native project and run

```
C:\Projects\myproject>react-native run-android
```

> info JS server already running. info Building and installing the app
>   on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...
>
> > Task :app:installDebug 01:03:18 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config 01:03:18 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554'
> >     : EOF hit. Read: -1 01:03:18 V/ddms: execute: returning Installing APK
> >     'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel_2_API_28(AVD) - 9' for app:debug 01:03:18
> >     D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
> >     01:03:18 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554' 01:03:18
> >     D/ddms: Reading file permision of
> >     C:\Projects\xx\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
> >     as: rwx------ 01:03:18 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t
> >     "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk" 01:03:19 V/ddms: execute 'pm install
> >     -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1 01:03:19 V/ddms: execute: returning 01:03:19 V/ddms: execute:
> >     running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk" 01:03:19 V/ddms: execute
> >     'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit.
> >     Read: -1 01:03:19 V/ddms: execute: returning Installed on 1 device.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 9s 27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date
>   info Running
>   C:\Users\codeb\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s
>   emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 info Starting the app on
>   emulator-5554
>   (C:\Users\codeb\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s
>   emulator-5554 shell am start -n
>   com.myproject/com.myproject.MainActivity)... Starting:
>   Intent { cmp=com.myproject/.MainActivity }

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I bought new m1 proccessor Macbook Air. After installed the java last release 18.0.3. Then I got same error. When i open the new project, ı got no error. Because, when ı open the old project in github repo, ı got same error.
Try this

- Remove the java last release on your computer.
- Install the java sdk 11 or 13. Doesn't matter.

And the problem will be solved.
[Remove the Java last release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFdpI.png)